# I'm new to Windows PowerShell. How can I covert %2F to /?

Tags: php, windows, powershell

I selected all of the pertinent files, then from the directory which was automatically listed when I opened the files in Windows PowerShell, then I typed the following command:

```
fully_qualified_dir_here> dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '%2F', '/'}
```

After hitting enter, I get the following error:

```
rename-item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:7
+ dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '%2F', '/'}
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\xampp\htdocs...icted\mapnik\16:String) [Rename-Item],
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I think this has to do with `%2F`, but I'm not sure. I got a bunch of Map Tiles using PHP and I misnamed them, thinking I could change them later, but Apache Server has a problem converting `%2F`. Now, I can't rename them and get them to go into their correct folders. I did already make the folders.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if the file name actually contains the text to process only the relevant items
2. Use `Move-Item` because `/` denotes a sub-directory so you need to move the file
3. Ensure the sub-directory part of the name exists or force-create it

```
dir *%2F* | %{
    $newName = $_.name -replace '%2F', '/'
    mkdir (split-path $newName) -force
    move $_ $newName
}
```

Comment: My files look like 0%2F12%2F925.png and I want it to look like 0/12/925.png. Will that do the job for sure? It's a lot of files?

Comment: Yeah, I already made the directories. The files like 0%2F12%2F925.png are sitting in the same parent directory, so those folders exist. This is my first PowerShell use ever. I do JavaScript and PHP normally.

Comment: Yes, I already created those directories, I also want to make sure they are not overwritten. In other words, I have directory 0 in mapnik folder (parent), then inside that directory 12, but all the files are in mapnik.

Comment: If php's `rename()` worked with `%2F` it would automatically move the files into the appropriate folders.

Comment: 0%2F12%2F925.png path ends up 0/12/925.png - 1%2F10%2F32.png path ends up 1/10/32.png.

Comment: Thanks, I have 200,000 files in the folder. The test worked! I'll vote you the victor soon! Once again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh, what does mkdir do on directories that already exist? If it overwrites I just made a huge mistake.

Comment: `mkdir` does nothing when a directory exists. FWIW directories cannot be "overwritten" anyway.

Comment: @wOxxOm _FWIW directories cannot be "overwritten" anyway_. That is not 100% true. You can overwrite folder symlinks with `new-item -force`

Comment: No, symlink is not a directory.

Comment: `[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")` and then instead of `$_.name -replace '%2F', '/'` use `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode('$_')` in full generality.

Comment: Yeah. BTW this class is already loaded on modern PowerShell at least (5.1)